How to fit a mirror to this wall without drilling?
I feel like I am a bit stumped. I would like to place this mirror (60cm x 90cm, first image below) onto this wall (67cm x 94cm, second image below).
I originally planned on using adhesive tape, however since there is a 2cm clearance at the back of the mirror between the edges of the mirror and the inside (third picture below), there is not enough space to place the adhesive tape.
Is there any other ways of doing this without drilling into the walls?




Tape or adhesive is just asking for seven years of bad luck.  What is the reason for not wanting to drill/screw into the wall?   The mirror has attachments for screws to hang up.

It's a rental, they requested that we do not drill into the wall

I would suggest gluing a 1x3 or 1x4 to the wall and placing screws into the wood to hold the mirror.  Make sure to clean both surfaces before gluing.

adhesive could easily damage the wall finish when the mirror is removed ... build a spring-loaded frame that fits into the wall cutout and holds in place by friction

How deep is that niche?  Looks more than 2 cm to me.

If you mean for the mirror to cover that cut-out in the wall, easiest would be to cut a piece of plywood, or make a frame from small lumber, that has a sliding fit into the hole, with perhaps a cm room around it (not critical).
Fasten that panel or frame so that it cannot fall out. Some ways to do so:

In each corner of the wood, place a wood screw so that it expands the material around it, forcing it against the surround.
Near each corner, mount a spring latch, such asthis example on Amazon, so that there is spring pressure holding the panel in place. The tips of the latch pins could be sharpened to point to better hold.
Use some type of adhesive around the edge, such as silicone caulking, that is strong enough to hold the frame in place, yet can be peeled off without damaging paint when you depart.

Then use hardware to attach the mirror to the frame.
N.B. It is up to you, as renter, to ensure that you do not damage the property. Check that the mounting surface will not be damaged by the weight of the mirror, or by the pressure to hold it in place, or by adhesive.
